# Vue mutation type intellisense VS Code

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vetur

Is there a way to get intellisense to work for imported mutation types with Vue and VS Code. I have the Vetur extension installed and I am using constant named mutations.

I want to have a file - *mutation-types.js*

```
export default {
     MY_MUTATION_TYPE: 'MY_MUTATION_TYPE',
     ANOTHER_MUTATION_TYPE: 'ANOTHER_MUTATION_TYPE'
}
```

then whenever I import:

```
import mutationTypes from './mutation-types'
```

I want to have intelisense on the *mutationTypes* object.

Is this is anyway possible?

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this wrong and throwing syntax errors?

It should be:

```
export default {
  MY_MUTATION_TYPE: 'MY_MUTATION_TYPE',
  ANOTHER_MUTATION_TYPE: 'ANOTHER_MUTATION_TYPE',
}
```

That would make auto complete work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That was just a mistake in typing out the question. Even with the correct syntax the intelisense is not working.

Comment: I'd try something as basic as restarting Code. I've run into situations like this, no idea how, and a restart helped.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing default export, in your import you also should use default import syntax. In your case mutationTypes can be any name, so that's why autocomplete will not work in the import. It will work on the object itself though:

[image]

To make it work in imports, you should use named exports.